# Checking hgrc file into Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I have a project using mercurial for version control, SCons to build, and google test to write unit tests. The hgrc file hooks pre-commit and runs SCons to build the project and and run unit tests. Is there a way to "check-in" a portion of the hgrc file so that newly checked out copies, and any merges with my version of the project automatically get an hgrc file that runs SCons when they try to commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get people to automatically have entries in their `.hg/hgrc` when they clone -- doing so would make it possible for someone to put `rm -rf ~` in a commit hook, and wouldn't that be a bummer for the erstwhile cloners.

What you can do is include a file named something like `mandatory.hgrc` outside of the `'hg` directory and then tell cloners to put this line in their `.hg/hgrc`:

```
%include ../mandatory.hgrc
```

Though that's still showing an awful lot of trust in you.

If you control the machines, as in many corporate settings, you can have your package/deployment/update tools (we use puppet) put whatever you want in their `/etc/mercurial/hgrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot checking anything under the .hg folder.  What my team does it that we have a common mercurial.ini file which as part of the dev box setup we put in our user profile folders.